# Правильное сокращение: русск. яз. или рус. яз

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно сократить «русский язык»: *русск. яз.* или *рус. яз.*?

Answer (score 4):

В Правилах-1956 в § 116 дано:
При стечении двух одинаковых согласных сокращение следует делать после первой согласной, например: стен. календарь, грам. ошибка (а не «стенн.», «грамм.»). При стечении двух различных или нескольких согласных сокращение следует делать после последней согласной, например: народн. творчество (а не «народ.»), русск. язык (а не «рус.»), искусств. шелк (а не «искус.», или «искусс.», или «искусст.»).

У Мильчина даны рекомендации по сокращению слов, которыми пользуются при вычитке разных произведений. 
Например: 4. Если перед отсекаемой частью слова стоит удвоенная согласная, то при сокращении одна из них отсекается. Напр.: классический — клас., металлический — метал.
Можно посмотреть здесь http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/4.html

Comment: Ну это не "правила русского языка", максимум - орфографии.
И потом, если понимать буквально, то первая чать противоречит второй.

Comment: Ну это не "правила русского языка", максимум - орфографии.


Самые настоящие правила )


И потом, если понимать буквально, то первая чать противоречит второй.


Не надо понимать буквально. Мильчин пишет:
Хотя этот список предназначен для сокращения слов и словосочетаний, употребляемых в библиогр. описании, т. е. в тексте спец. характера, он вполне применим и в обычном тексте изданий спец. лит. для подготовленного читателя.
И вообще, у него рекомендации как раз, а не правила.

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно сократить «русский язык»: *русск. яз.* или *рус. яз.*?

Лучше: ***рус. яз***.

Именно такие сокращения слов *русский* и *язык* зафиксированы в приложении 1 к "Русскому орфографическому словарю" под ред. Лопатина (М., 2012).

См.:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По правилам русского языка слово сокращается на согласную перед гласным. Т.е. русск. яз. будет правильно.

Comment: А где такие правила *русского языка* прописаны?