# Подд. или под.?

Tags: орфография

В справочнике Лопатина написано, что в букв. сокращениях мы две буквы пишем, если слово две содержит и если эти две буквы не находятся на стыке корня слова и его суффикса, как, напрмер, в слове *обещанный* (*обещан.*) или как в *клёванная (*клёван.*) воронами чёрная черника*. Вот параграф таки (§ 209): https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/

Я хочу знать, однако, нужно ли две или одну букву писать, если мы сокращаем слово, в котором две буквы пересекаются **на стыке префикса и корня слова**. Так, я не знаю, как правильно сокращать след. слова: *подделка* (*под.* или *подд.*?), *ссылка, рассориться.*

Comment: Материал по этой же теме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/Правильное-сокращение-русск-яз-или-рус-яз

Comment: У слова сокращают корень, а не приставку/префикс. Если хотят сократить совсем, сокращают по первой литере. Смысла сокращения до приставки/префикса нет, потомучто слова не будет. Слово - это корень. Морфема - это корень со значащими элементами. Морфему можно урезать, корень - нет.

Comment: Правила сокращения слов (руководство)  http://olgadyachenko.ru/pravila-sokrashcheniya-slov.html